# have any php free pdf library support css float property

Tags: php, pdf-generation, codeigniter-2

i used **dompdf** as php pdf library with  **codeigniter** project but it doesn't support css float property. But i need this property supported free pdf library.

And other hand if i use lot of table then it takes to much time to generate pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in its latest version (which is 0.6 beta 3) you can enable it in the config. It's still experimental but it worked fine for me

Comment: thanks i use "DOMPDF 0.6.0 beta 3" but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: you enabled the feature in the config?

Comment: def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_CSS_FLOAT", true); i set this in dompdf_config.inc.php

Answer (score 0):

Look at this answer of mine
cezpdf is alternative and easy to use

[cezPDF in Codeigniter 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224501/cezpdf-in-codeigniter-2)

Also here is a simple tutorial to use it

http://www.christophermonnat.com/2008/08/generating-pdf-files-using-codeigniter/