# Generating PDF files from Database using CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, pdf-generation

Generating PDF files from Database using CodeIgniter 
for example,

when i click save button all contents in the table can downloaded as pdf format
please help me
thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this article.

http://www.christophermonnat.com/2008/08/generating-pdf-files-using-codeigniter/

Also my answer is helful too.

[cezPDF in Codeigniter 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224501/cezpdf-in-codeigniter-2)

on the user click you should hit a controller function which will query the database and load a view file which you can pass to this library and it will throw it as pdf.

Comment: thanks for the help....
i got one more link
(http://www.code2learn.com/2012/02/generating-pdf-files-from-database.html)
its also a good tutorial...

Answer (score 0):

There is no native PDF library in CodeIgniter, so you need to use an third party library or a third party software-as-a-service (SaaS) to generate the PDF.

Here is what I did for one client.

I first generate a nicely formatted, print-friendly HTML page using standard CodeIgniter techniques to select the data from the relevant table, sort it, and echo to the page.

Next, I use the following SasS to turn my formatted HTML page into a PDF download:

http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk

This is a commercial system, but relatively affordable and quick and easy to use.

Alternatively, if you want to do some custom programming, you can try:

http://html2pdf.fr

In this case, you need to link to the class file (external to CodeIgniter) and call
the various methods to generate the PDF.  This approach does not require an annual fee
but it will take more programming effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use codeginter's database utility for getting backup in txt format first http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/utilities.html#backup

Then you can read the generated file and convert it in pdf using https://github.com/aiwmedia/HTML2PDF-CI

This pdf will you can give for download